# Can body-only exports be performed by default?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have an `org` file:

```
#+TITLE: Hello!

Hello world!
```

I can perform a "body-only" export of this file to `html` by issuing `C-c C-e C-b h h`. Here, the `C-b` keystroke toggles the "body-only" variable from `Off` to `On`.

Is it possible to set the default value of "body-only" for my org file to `On`? It seems that something like

```
#+TITLE: Hello!
#+OPTIONS: body-only:t

Hello world!
```

should work.

Comment: It does seem like this should be possible, but from browsing the source (ox.html) it seems like body-only and visible-only are handled separately from other org options, and I can't see an obvious way to make this work.